# UML: Method diagram instead of class diagram?

Tags: java, uml

I want to diagram the chain of methods required when someone pushes a button or initialization to when the task has been completed. What would be the best UML diagram for this, if any?

I've been researching this for the last few days and am unable to find anyone employing this type of diagram. Is UML not suitable for this, or is there a reason that this evidently isn't useful to anyone else?

```
public static void storeHistory() {
    checkIfTitlePresent();
}

private static void checkIfTitlePresent() {
    if (CategoryMangaLists.history.stream().noneMatch(v -> v.getTitleId() == CategoryMangaLists.selectedMangaIdentNumber)) {
        addTitleTohistory();
    }
}
```

Basically I want a visual roadmap akin to storeHistory() has been called by another class, it in turn calls checkIfTitlePrsent(), at this point id break into a fork for the if statement and keep mapping

I also welcome any arguments against this concept in case I'm just not structuring my program correctly.

Comment: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

- Activity diagram
- Sequence diagram

### Full answer

I don't know where did you look but apparently something went wrong with your search

Basically UML diagrams are grouped into two main groups: static diagrams and behavioural diagrams.

Static diagrams, class diagram included, focus mostly on the structure of the system. They may be capable of showing some behavioural features, such as operations of a class, but they do not show how the system behaves.

Behavioural diagrams are on the other end of focus, specifically on what (and how) the system does.

Two most notable, useful and popular are activity diagram and sequence diagram. They are centred around slightly different things but both are fully capable of showing what you depict. In many aspects they are interchangeable.

Personally I would most probably go with an activity diagram in your case but it's best to test both and see which one works best when.

Note, UML is not limited to three diagrams I mention explicitly. Reading any good book about modelling using UML should be a start.